# joint distribution and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am confused about conditional expectations. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Next, let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables on this space. Next, let $E[X|\sigma(Y)]$ be conditional expectation, which is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable random variable, and, therefore, also $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

The question: can we define joint distribution of $E[X|\sigma(Y)]$, $Y$ and $X$?

Ok, for example, $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Normal. What would be a distribution of $(E[X|\sigma(Y)], X, Y)$?

Comment: Yes, just call the given conditional expectation "$Z$", then $(Z,Y,X)$ are just three random variables and they have a joint distribution. Whether you can explicitly write it is a whole different question, though...

Comment: thank you, I would like to have an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal; [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2)

$$Z = E(X | \sigma (Y)) = \mu_X + \frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}\rho (Y - \mu_Y)$$

which is readily seen to be normally distributed as well, and the vector $(Z,X,Y)$ is jointly Gaussian. It's a simple exercise from here to compute its mean and covariance.

Comment: $(X,Y,Z)$ would have a degenerate multivariate normal distribution.